# SSRS 2008 R2: How to apply filtering on Excel columns while exporting report(.rdl)

Tags: .net, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, business-intelligence

**SSRS 2008 R2:** I have created a report(.rdl) using Shared datasource. I am following the tabular approach to generate the report. While exporting the report to excel I need to apply the filters to all the columns, so that the generated excel will have the filtration in its columns. But I am unable to find any option with respect to it.

**Current Generated excel**

[image: Current Result]

**Expected Generated excel**

[image: Expected Result with Filter]

Please let me know in case of any other information is required.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with SSRS

Comment: Please don't say NO, there has to be some option for it. I am messing up my mind with it to generate the reports like this. But isn't there any alternative with which we can achieve it. I mean it would be an extra work for the client that he has to apply the filter to all the columns (say 25).

Comment: why would it be extra work to apply filters? once the report is exported, click on the first row (on 1) and then click on Sort and Filters -> Filters.. it's a matter of 2 clicks.. you can have a 100 columns and the time it takes to apply the filter is the same.. Literally 2 seconds..

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. Even I am doing like this for now. But I was wondering if we can or can't apply the filter. For now, I haven't seen any option to do it as you have told.

Comment: Have you tried to create the filtering/sorting at the SSRS level first, then export? http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/joew/archive/2008/08/02/60666.aspx

Comment: Yes, I've tried to create sorting and filtering. But here the filtering refers to filter out the column data only. I am looking to put the filters on column level when exporting the report to excel. The link provided by you has only spoken about applying sorting to the generated excel columns.